# How to append a file by extension 'filename_ext'.txt and recursively to all the files in a folder and convert them back into the original extension

Tags: python, file, directory, scripting, filesystems

I have a code that recursively changes all the files with .py extension to .txt inside a folder.
which is :

```
def frm_ext_to_ext(directory, from_ext, to_ext):
       """
       directory, from_ext, to_ext should be passed as strings including '.'
       For example : directory = '/home/Desktop/folder/file',  from_ext = '.txt' ,  to_ext = '.py'
       """
       for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directory):
           for f in filenames :
               if f.endswith('.py'):
                   base = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
                   os.rename(os.path.join(foldername, f), os.path.join(foldername, base + to_ext))
```

But what I want is to change the filename like :

If a file name is `script.py`, I want it to be changed as `script_py.txt` to every file extension and I want another function to reverse this change i.e from `script_py.txt` to `script.py`. 
Note : Above `.py` was just an example. The extension could be anything like, `.pynb etc`
Also, If the extension is already `.txt`, I want it as it is.  Any help ?

Comment: Ok, sounds like some simple string manipulation. Can you please include what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you want

For more safety, you should do a script that check if there is a file contains more than one '.'

```
def frm_ext_to_ext(directory, from_ext, to_ext):
       for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directory):
           for f in filenames :
                ext = f.split('.')[1]               
                if(ext!='txt' and to_ext == 'txt'):
                    base = f.split('.')[0]
                    os.rename(os.path.join(foldername, f), os.path.join(foldername, base + '_' + ext + '.' + to_ext))
                elif(ext=='txt' and to_ext!='txt'):
                    base=f.split('_')[0]
                    os.rename(os.path.join(foldername, f), os.path.join(foldername, base + '.' + to_ext))
```

Usage:

```
frm_ext_to_ext(DIR, 'py', 'txt')
frm_ext_to_ext(DIR, 'txt', 'py')
```

Comment: This is alright but I don't want the `py` and `txt` as the arguments. I just want my argument to be `dir`. which converts any `file.ext` to `file_ext.txt ` and other function which converts `file_ext.txt`  to `file.ext`. Please note that I want to apply these functions to folders, files and subfolders at once recursively.

Answer (score 1):

since extensions are added after dot character in a filename, we can split the file_name with "." using file_name.split(".") and append last element with file name.
For example i have following files in my "D:\FlaskApp" directory

```
app.py
runApp.bat
demo.html
index.html
```

using split to append the extension:

```
import os
directory = "D:\FlaskApp"
for foldername, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(directory):
           for f in filenames :
              fl = f.split(".")
              print(fl[0] + "_" + fl[-1])
```

this gives:

```
app_py
runApp_bat
demo_html
index_html
```